# Change font color of pandas data frame charts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code, charts, jupyter-notebook

I am coding in Vscode on Ubuntu 20.04. I am using jupyter nb to execute some simple commands. I am using pandas library to build a histogram. The theme of vscode is dark which overshadows the black font color of axis numbers. Can I change them somehow
This is my current code

```
df = pd.DataFrame([2,5,67,2,3,5,23,124])
df.hist()
```

Comment: Press F1 to show all commands, then input "Preferences: Color Theme" to change your theme.